# How to catch any Jersey POST/GET request with AspectJ?

Tags: jersey, aspectj

I have a REST endpoint written with Jersey framework. I'd like to create an AspectJ pointcut that catches ANY Jersey GET/POST to inspect the params. For servlet it was easy:

```
"call(public java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameter(java.lang.String))"
```

Here's the code of the Jersey REST endpoint:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("/test/{username}")
    public class JerseyTest {

    @XmlRootElement
        public static class BigTest {
        public String name;
    }

  @GET
  @Produces("text/plain")
  public String getHello(BigTest test, @PathParam("username") String username) {
    return "hello " + username;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use execution() rather than call() if you can, but the signatures below would work with either. If your endpoints are identified by GET/POST:

`before(): execution(@GET * *(..)) || execution(@POST * *(..)) {
   Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
   ... do what you want with the args
}`

You could narrow the matching to methods in types with @Path on them:

`execution(@GET * *(..)) && @within(Path)`

If you want particular parameters:

`before(BigTest test): execution(@GET * *(..)) && args(test,..)`

but then you need to build specific binding args() clauses on a per endpoint basis - whereas using thisJoinPoint.getArgs() will work for anything.

Comment: This approach works. Sorry, cannot upvote due to lack of karma.

Comment: I actually did something different: stepped through the Jersey with the debugger and found out that it uses: HttpServletRequest.getQueryString(), getPath(), getRequestURL() getRequestURI. I already had rules for most of these, so adding the remaining ones was very quick.